# How to display and dynamically update a multiline result

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal

I have a script that repeatedly counts the number of the lines in a file and displays the number, dynamically updating it in place,
by continually overwriting the previous value with a carriage return.

```bsh
echo "Checking in progress:"
while true ; do
    outcount=$(cat /tmp/curl-check-result.txt | wc -l)
    echo -ne "Total checked IPs:" '\t'`cat /tmp/curl-check-result.txt | wc -l`'\r'
    if [[ $outcount -eq $numips ]]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

But I want to do a similar thing for two other files at the same time. 
Something like this:

```
Count file 1: count
Count file 2: count
Count file 3: count
```

When I try adding a similar part of code in the one script,
the output lines overwrite each other. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to print these lines once, or the output to be updated/refreshed. You have a `\r` now at the end of your line.

Comment: Yes, it's should be updatable like in my example. But I want it in 2-3 line on the same time. If it's in one line - everything is OK.

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement, pretty much :)

Comment: For anyone looking for the python equivalent, see this article: https://itnext.io/overwrite-previously-printed-lines-4218a9563527 (basically you use ANSI escape sequences).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man tput` to see that you can provide a "capname" with optional parameters.

`man terminfo (5)` to see what is available for "capname", a lot of capabilities.

Here is a demo for how to do this:

```bsh
while true; do
    var1=$((var1+1))
    var2=$((var2+2))
    var3=$((var3+3))

    printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
    [ $var1 -ge 100 ] && break

    sleep 0.1
    # move the cursor up 3 lines
    tput cuu 3
    # clear to the end of screen
    tput ed
done
```